# Not importing whole Excel worksheet into SAS month on month

Tags: excel, import, sas

I built a SAS application that imports an Excel worksheet for monthly reporting. To import the worksheet I used the "Open -> Data -> Local file" functionality of EG 4. For the first month that worked fine but the next month I noticed that if I have a worksheet with more rows than the initial one my code won't import all rows from the worksheet. Any ideas of fixing this so that I can just run my process flow without any manual adjustments month on month?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no code. All point and click in EG4. :(

Comment: @pnuts No, this isn't a SuperUser quesiton; EG is a programming tool, so on topic here.  (Not necessarily a good question, but not off topic for that reason.)

Comment: @user3016630 You don't provide enough information to usefully answer this question.  How many rows?  What kind of excel spreadsheet?  I'm not sure this question could be answered here, but you certainly could provide much more information than you have.

Comment: It is a 97-2003 workbook holding information such as account number, customer name, etc. (53 columns in total) for the last 12 months of business deals. As such the number of rows is changing month on month. Initially there were some 6000 rows while the next month it increased to nearly 8000 rows. Next month it might increase further or decline again.